# how to use divided in pandas pivot function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I want to divide the sum value in aggfun by 2 .

i want to this result :-

[image]

import pandas as pd

```
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'B','B', 'B','A', 'A','A', 'B',],
                   'points_for': ['18', '22', '19', '14', '14', '11', '20', '28'],
                   'points_against': ['aa','bb','aa','bb','aa','bb','aa','bb']})

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='points_for', index='team', columns='points_against', aggfunc=sum)
df2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide after pivot

```py
df2 = (pd.pivot_table(df, values='points_for', index='team', columns='points_against', aggfunc=sum)
       .astype(int).div(2))
```

```
print(df2)

points_against       aa        bb
team
A               90710.0       5.5
B                   9.5  110714.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(df2.astype(int) / 2)
```

Prints:

```
points_against       aa        bb
team                             
A               90710.0       5.5
B                   9.5  110714.0
```